# Android Network Monitor

Tags: android, open-source, network-monitor, vpn

I'm looking for an Android app that:

- Is gratis and open-source
- Registers itself as VPN (so that it works without root)
- Shows all connections made on my device, with the following information:

  - IP address
  - Domain
  - Type (HTTP, TLS, TCP, UDP, etc.)
  - If HTTP:

    - Path
    - Headers
    - Data (gunzipped if it's using gzip)
- Doesn't mess with TLS connections

Comment: While waiting for good recommendations, you might wish to have a look at [my corresponding app listing](https://android.izzysoft.de/applists/category/named/network_admin_diagnosis#group_1006) – and especially [this post at our Android sister site](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/160593/16575), which sounds like coming very close to what you're looking for.

Comment: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.glasswire.android&hl=en

Comment: no-root firewall maybe is a solution for you?